# Does the function override the base function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have three different compilers that I am using to compile this code. One of them (the one that I trust the least) warns that the function in Derived hides the function in Base. The other compilers (one is [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_versions)) does not warn. Visual C++ doesn't even give a warning about it if I enable /Wall or /W4.

I tend to believe that this is a bug in the compiler that's giving a warning, since it compiles the code. If it really didn't override the base function, then it should give an error when I create an instance of the derived template.

Can anyone confirm how this should behave?

```
struct Base
{
   virtual void Func(float f) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base
{
   virtual void Func(T f){}
};

int main()
{
   Derived<float> d;
   d.Func(0);
   return 0;
}
```

---

When `Derived` is instantiated with `float` I get the unexpected warning.  When `Derived` is instantiated with `int` I get an error, as expected.

Comment: What's wrong with a warning on valid code that might not do what you expect? For example, `if (b = true)` would usually cause a warning.

Comment: i dont think it should produce a warning at all - there is nothing wrong with the code. I have never seen this kind of thing (a derived class using templated function), it made me think hard (ouch)

Comment: I have a feeling that it does in fact hide function in Base because if you try to do this: Base *b = new Derived<bool>(); in your main it'll give you compile error: error C2259: 'Derived<bool>' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void Base::Func(float)' : is abstract

So this looks fishy to me.

Comment: @RedOctober What's fishy about it? `Derived::func(bool)` doesn't override `Base::func(float)` so it hides it.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I see what you mean. Well, fishy in the sense that it's a weird way to do inheritance. The only way you'd be able to use Derived is if you template it to float, which kind of defeats the purpose of a template.

Comment: This is a trivial example based on some code that is in the middle of refactoring.  I agree that currently it doesn't make much since, since it is only valid to instantiate `Derived<float>`.

Comment: Which compiler is warning on this?

Comment: TI compiler for C6000 DSP.

Comment: @Graznarak it's valid to instantiate other types; they won't override

Comment: @MattMcNabb You are correct.  It is valid to instantiate the template, but it is not valid to create an instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed overridden. You can easily convince yourself in C++11 using the `override` keyword, which won't allow code to compile if the function is not overridden:

```
struct Base
{
   virtual void Func(float f) = 0;
   virtual ~Base() = default; // to silence warnings
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base
{
   void Func(T f) override {} // will fail to compile if not overriding
};

int main()
{
   Derived<float> d;
   d.Func(0);
   return 0;
}
```

Live example [here](http://ideone.com/faZlN0).

Note that in pre C++11, you can accidentally hide a `virtual` base function via changing its signature in a derived class, so even if you mark the derived function `virtual` the code still compiles, but does is not polymorphic anymore, see such an example [here](http://ideone.com/RhqUJT). Unfortunately g++ doesn't provide any warnings, even with `-Wall -Wextra`. That's why `override` is a much safer way of actually enforcing true override at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you should be given a warning.
This is the same as:

```
struct Derived : Base
{
  virtual void Func(float f) { };
};
```

When your template parameter is `float`.

There is no hiding, only implementation of an abstract function.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, the warning that a function is hidden is letting us know that a member function in the derived class has the same name, but a different signature than than a function in the base class. Consider:

```
struct Base
{
    void foo(int) {}
    void bar(int) {}
};

struct Derived: Base
{
    void bar(int, int) {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.foo(1);
    d.bar(1); // will not compile: Base::bar is hidden by Derived::bar
}
```

In this example, the intention may have been to add an additional function named "bar," but the result is that compiler stops looking for new scopes with functions name bar once it finds a scope with a function named bar. So bar(int) is hidden by bar(int, int) (or any other bar with a non matching signature). (Or in the non-virtual case, even if the functions match.)

In this Graznarak's code, Base::Func is hidden in any situation where Derived is instantiated for any value of T that is not float (or float const).

Graznarak asks about the correct behavior. The correct before for the generated code is not in question Derived::Func() is called.

But that leaves the question: Is the warning proper. The standard has no answer. It never expresses an opinion on whether or not a warning should be generated. Whether or not to warn about a particular issues is always subjective and compilers can distinguish themselves by showing good judgement in this regard.

So should your compiler warn about this situation? Arguable, the code as written does what is probably intended. But the existence of a template implies that it will be instantiated on more than one type (else why make a template) and for any other type, hiding would happen. So one could argue that the warning should be given with the creation of the derived template. But one could also argue that the warning shouldn't happen until the a non-float type instantiation is specified.

Arguing for the former is that the warning would be earlier and likely detected by the programmer writing the problematic code. Arguing for the later is that until a non-float type is instantiated, no suspicious situation exists to be warned about.